# For, delims, DIR, SET in batch files

Tags: file, batch-file

Can someone please help me understand command file syntax

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
pushd c:\test
FOR /f "delims=" %%g IN ('DIR /b /a-d /o-d /tw') DO (
SET zold=%%g  
SET zoldname=%%~ng
)
move /y %zold% C:\Another\Location\%zoldname%.bat
popd 
exit /b
```

This is my first bat file and my first try in coding in general there are couple commands I dont understand yet.

Why z before old? What is %%g? What does IN ('DIR /b /a-d /o-d /tw') mean?

Comment: The best I can help you is to provide you with the help. open `cmd` on your computer, then type each of the following and read the details provided. `for /?` and `set /?` then `dir /?` and maybe even `setlocal /?` You can additionally run `help` to see a full list of windows commands available on commandline.

Comment: Command Prompt Cheat Sheet https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: additionally, you say this is your first try at batch, yet you ask why you placed  the z before old? Seems like you just got the code from someone and trying to find out what exactly it does.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard thanks for the advice and yes, I got the code from someone. I tried myself first but failed so I got help

Comment: But that then makes your question off topic here. We do not request books or sources to explain code here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Pushd` changes the current directory to "C:\Test".

`dir /b /a-d /o-d /tw` is used to list files. `/b` shows only the file names (bare info). `/a-d` excludes directories. `/o-d` sorts by date (newest first). `/tw` sets "last write time" as sort criteria for `/o-d`.

`for /f` is used to parse the output of `dir` command. `delims` is used to add a delimiter set ("nothing" in this case). And there is also another `tokens` keyword to get a specific field splitted by the delimiter(s) in `delims`. `%%g` is the `for` meta variable that contains the parsed token(s) and can be used in the `do` part. You can even change the `%%g` to `%%a` or any alphabet. In the `in` the command is specified in brackets. `do` is the statements where work is done.

`set` is used to set variables. Variables contain data. Then `%%~ng` is used to get the name of file without quotes. The `~` and `n` are the modifiers of `%%g`.

`move` command moves files from source to destination directory.

`popd` pops directory to set the current directory to the directory before the pushed directory.

`exit /b` exits current batch file.

Please open cmd and look at the output of these commands:

- set /?
- for /?
- setlocal /?
- exit /?
- move /?

Comment: @Lloyd: read again, I corrected some minor mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, for the mistakes. Please don't take it to the heart. Thank you for being helped.

Comment: @Wasif Hasan so I want the script to rename the latest file in a folder, moves it to another folder and renames it again. I tried to test the code but nothing happens.. can you tell whats wrong?

Comment: @llo your original question asked how to work on the oldest file.  your comment says `latest`.  which do you want? oldest or newest?

Comment: @somebadhat Sorry for the confusion, I mean the oldest file

Comment: @llo does `c:\another\location` exist? post results of ``dir /ad c:\``

Comment: @somebadhat Yes it does exist, Im just getting a syntax error

Comment: @Lloyd: do your filenames contain spaces? Change the syntax to `move /y "%zold%" "C:\Another\Location\%zoldname%.bat" - and for heaven's sake, remove the trailing spaces in `SET zold=%%g<space><space>` or better use the recommended syntax `set "zold=%%g"`